# Experiencing Wi-Fi connection drops when bluetooth speaker is connected

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, bluetooth, connection-issues, huawei

I have a Huawei P9 Lite with Android 6.0. 
My issue is that whenever a bluetooth speaker is connected, the phone's wifi periodically loses internet connection. Also my Lumia 730 doesn't have this problem.

I've tried the following:

- Changing router's wireless channels (just 2.4 GHz connection, no 5GHz option)
- Upgrading router's firmware
- Tried with 2 bluetooth speakers

Update: I tried with a Samsung Galaxy J5 and this also happened.

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you!